# countdown timer based on window local storage

Tags: javascript, electron, local-storage

I am working on a simple Electron app project. So far I am only at the Javascript and HTML stage.
I am making a countdown timer where the user enters a future date –their birthday for example– and the app then displays a counter with the remaining days, hours, minutes and seconds. You only see the input fields at first, then a simple toggle function removes the input fields and brings up a large clock instead.

So far I have a working prototype with a basic styling. But this prototype will need a new input every time you bring it up. If I can make the window local storage work, then I would get a website (hence Electron app) that will remember your special date even when closed.

My failed attempt at coding below (see headline with 'local storage problem' in capitol letters) has been taken from various youtube tutorials and StackOverflow questions. But I guess I am missing a fairly basic principle in order to make it work.

All suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="javascript" src="p5.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <script>

     
     
        // Event listener made to work with Materialize's .hide class

        let hideInput = document.getElementById('input-hide');
        // console.log(hideInput);
        let hideCountdown = document.getElementById('countdown-hide');
        // console.log(hideCountdown);
        let button = document.querySelector("button");
        // console.log(button);

        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (hideInput.classList.contains("hide")) {
                hideInput.classList.remove("hide");
                hideCountdown.setAttribute("class", "hide")

            } else {
                hideInput.setAttribute("class", "hide");
                hideCountdown.classList.remove("hide");
            }
        });


        // Find the user's input

        const Calender = document.querySelector('.datepicker');
        M.Datepicker.init(Calender, {
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            firstDay: 1,
            // minDate: '15 05 2021', <-- I could't get this to work...

        })

        // Create a countdown timer and display the user's text

        function enterSpecialDate() {

            let userDate = new Date(document.getElementById('special-date').value);
            // console.log(userDate);
            let currentTime = new Date();
           
/////// LOCAL STORAGE PROBLEM ///////

            // window.localStorage.setItem("storedObject", userDate.value);
            // console.log(storedObject);
            // console.log(dtUserDate);

            // let diff = storedObject - currentTime;

            let diff = userDate - currentTime;


            /* we've been given the difference in milliseconds, so some division is needed */
            const d = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
            const h = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24;
            const m = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60) % 60;
            const s = Math.floor(diff / 1000) % 60;


            /* send values back into HTML document */
            document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = d;
            document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = h;
            document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = m;
            document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = s;

            // console.log(s < 10 ? ‘0’ + s : s;) <-- I could't get this to work...

            /*collect user's special occasion and send back into document*/
            var userOccasion = document.getElementById('user-occasion').value;
            document.getElementById('userOccasionOutput').innerHTML = userOccasion;
            console.log(document.getElementById('user-occasion').value);

        }
        setInterval(enterSpecialDate, 1000);
```

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- welcome message and input area - should show on start then dissappear after you click buttton-->

        <div class="" id="input-hide">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col s12 m12 distance-1"></div>

                <div class="col s12 m3"></div>
                <div class="col s12 m6">

                    <h2>
                        Countdown to your special occasion!
                    </h2>

                </div>
                <div class="col s12 m3"></div>
            </div>



            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 m3"></div>
                <div class="col s12 m6">
                    <form action="">

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <textarea class="materialize-textarea" name="user-occasion" id="user-occasion"
                                placeholder="e.g. my birthday"></textarea>
                            <label for="user-occasion">what is your special occasion?</label>
                        </div>


                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col s12 m3"></div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 m3"></div>
                <div class="col s12 m6">
                    <form action="">
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <input type="text" id="special-date" class="datepicker" placeholder="click here">
                            <label for="date">when is your special occasion?</label>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <button onclick="enterSpecialDate()">Enter</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col s12 m3"></div>

            </div>

        </div>


        <!-- countdown ticker - should appear only after you click the button -->

        <div class="hide" id="countdown-hide">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col s12 m12 distance-2">
                    <p></p>

                </div>


                <div class="col s12 m12">

                    <div class="time col s12 m3">
                        <span class="number" id="days"></span>
                        <br>
                        <span id="unit">days</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="time col s12 m3">
                        <span class="number" id="hours"></span>
                        <br>
                        <span id="unit">hours</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="time col s12 m3">
                        <span class="number" id="minutes"></span>
                        <br>
                        <span id="unit">minutes</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="time col s12 m3">
                        <span class="number" id="seconds"></span>
                        <br>
                        <span id="unit">seconds</span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- <div class="time col s12 m3"></div> -->
                </div>

                <div class="col s12 m12 distance-3"></div>

                <div class="col s12 m12">

                    <div class="time col s12 m12 until">
                        <span>until </span><span id="userOccasionOutput"></span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col s12 m12">
                        <a href="javascript:location.reload(true)">start again</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    </div>
```

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/DatePicker1.css">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see the problem.

I've just made something like this for a **'promo'**.

I haven't tested your code, but in order to make it work using localStorage,
I would, and did, something like this:

1. Retrieve user inputs **ONCE**, after checking if localStorage hasn't that item.

   ```
    if (!localStorage.getItem('birthday_key_HASH'))
        // Retrieve user's input and then store it.
        let userDate = new Date(document.getElementById('special-date').value);
        localStorage.setItem('birthday_key_HASH', userDate);
   ```
2. If it's already set, just do your math using the user birthday value.

   ```
    // ...Do your calculus.
    userBirthdayDate = localStorage.getItem('birthday_key_HASH');
   ```

Let me know if this is clear enough.